# Recovering a large archive created without zip64

Tags: compression, zip, zlib

I had created a large archive using an old version of [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) version 1.01h which is based on [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) library. It does not support Zip64. 
The source file was a text file much larger than 4GB. 
The compressed size of the archive is 2GB. 
Since it was created without Zip64 support the archive is corrupt. I am unable to restore the archive. Is there a way to recover at least a part of the text file from this corrupt archive?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this streaming unzip](http://zlib.net/sunzip033.c.gz), which ignores the central directory.

Comment: Where can i find the header files required for this ?Alternately is there a binary which supports streaming unzip?

Comment: In [zlib](http://zlib.net/) and [libbzip2](http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html).  infback9 can be found in the zlib distribution in `contrib/infback9`.  zlib may already be installed on your system.

Comment: I have trouble compiling sunzip. Is there any documentation or an alternate binary capable of ignoring the central directory?

Comment: What trouble?  No, there are no binaries.

Comment: i get the error "unknown zip header flags set". I cannot find any option to force unzip ignoring the error. This is while processing local header part of the code.

Comment: That's odd.  minizip should not have set any unknown flags.  Please provide a hex dump of the first 100 bytes of the zip file in your question.

Comment: the value of general purpose flags , method , crc is same for a test archive created with the library using ZIP64 is same as that without ZIP64. But the value of compressed, uncompressed size , filename length appears to be wrong in case of the corrupt archive.

Comment: Please provide a hex dump of the first 100 bytes of the zip file in your question.

Comment: Also size of both the archives are same on disk.

Comment: 0000000: 504b 0304 1400 0008 0800 0000 2000 0d09  PK.......... ...
0000010: f2a0 d6ed 8cac 7a44 57b2 504b 0102 0000  ......zDW.PK....
0000020: 1400 0008 0800 0000 2000 0d09 f2a0 d6ed  ........ .......
0000030: 8cac 7a44 57b2 2500 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..zDW.%.........
0000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 6261 636b 7570 5f64  ........backup_d
0000050: 656c 6574 655f 6166 7465 725f 7465 7374  elete_after_test
0000060: 696e 675f                                ing_

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45293/discussion-between-user1391868-and-mark-adler)

Comment: No need.  I can't help.  minizip overwrote the start of your compressed data with the central header.  It cannot be recovered.